# Trigger needs to use inserted record columns in select

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

We have a shipping table that has an orderID (oid) and an invoice number (ino) and a sequnce number columns.   I am trying to write  a trigger that sets a sequnce number to zero or increments it if a unique set of oid,ino,seq exists.  I am not sure how to reference the OID and INO columns of the inserted record?

Here's what I got so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SHPVIAb_insert ON [acsdcs2].[dbo].[SHPVIAb]
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @newseq tinyint;
SET @newseq = 0;
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM [acsdcs2].[dbo].[SHPVIAb] s 
           WHERE s.SHVOID_AN = inserted.SHVOID_AN
             AND s.SHVINO_AN = inserted.SHVINO_AN
          )
  BEGIN
    SET @newseq = (SELECT MAX(SHVSEQ_US)
           FROM [acsdcs2].[dbo].[SHPVIAb] s 
           WHERE s.SHVOID_AN = inserted.SHVOID_AN
             AND s.SHVINO_AN = inserted.SHVINO_AN)
    SET @newseq = @newseq + 1
  END

update [acsdcs2].[dbo].[SHPVIAb]
   set SHVSEQ_US=@newseq;
```

Comment: what database backend? Code for triggers is extremely database specific

Comment: I can tell you that if this is for SQl server (which I suspect fromthe inserted psuedotablerefernce), your trigger is poorly written becasue it assumes there will never be more than one record in the inserted table. This is an assuption it is very bad to make when writing a trigger, they fire only one for all records in thr batch.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is closer to what you want.  You want to join to the inserted table, and handle the situation where more than one record is being inserted at a time.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SHPVIAb_insert ON [acsdcs2].[dbo].[SHPVIAb]
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    [acsdcs2].[dbo].[SHPVIAb] s
                        INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON s.SHVOID_AN = i.SHVOID_AN
                                                 AND s.SHVINO_AN = i.SHVINO_AN ) 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  s
            SET     SHVSEQ_US = ( SELECT    MAX(SHVSEQ_US)
                                  FROM      [acsdcs2].[dbo].[SHPVIAb] ss
                                  WHERE     ss.SHVOID_AN = s.SHVOID_AN
                                            AND ss.SHVINO_AN = s.SHVINO_AN
                                ) + 1
            FROM    [acsdcs2].[dbo].[SHPVIAb] s
                    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON s.SHVOID_AN = i.SHVOID_AN
                                             AND s.SHVINO_AN = i.SHVINO_AN 
        END
END
```